# Find mean and standard deviation of all number in a list

Tags: r

I was trying to find the mean and standard deviation of the 100 samples of 36 sets of 3 coin flip with a binomial distribution. But it shows up an error message on the mean(a) and sd(a).

```
a = list()
for (i in 1:100){
     flips <- rbinom(36,3,0.5)
     a <- append(a, mean(flips))
     }
mean(a)
sd(a)
```

Comment: Instead of storing the data in list, store it in vector. `a = vector()` then you can do `mean(a)`

Comment: Do you really need `a` to be a list? You probably would be just fine with a vector which would allow you to use `mean` and `sd`, otherwise `unlist()` the values with `mean(unlist(a))`. You can also skip the loop with `a <- replicate(100, mean(rbinom(36,3,0.5)))` which would work with `mean` and `sd`